# В чём ошибка в preventDefault?

Tags: javascript

Делаю красивое подтверждение вместо стандартного JS confirm в стиле alert, код такой: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/veqKdO но при клике всё равно переходит по ссылке и `event.preventDefault();` не срабатывает.

1) В чём я ошибся

2) Правильно ли сделано подтверждение у Согласен и Отмена где `return true / false`?

HTML

```
<div onclick="return add()"><a href="https://ya.ru">перейти по ссылке</a></div>
<br><br>
<div id="test">
    <div class="line" onclick="return true">Согласен</div>
    <div class="line" onclick="return false">Отмена</div>
</div>
```

CSS (не принципиален)

```
#test{
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JS

```
var add = function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('клик');
  $("#test").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Comment: `return add(???)` - где параметр? Не срабатывает `undefined.preventDefault();`.

Comment: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined_ - при клике

Comment: @Igor да, благодарю, в этом и была тут ошибка, добавил event всё заработало, но дальше с `return true / false` виидмо неверно сделал

Comment: @Grundy благодарю, исправил, добавил, а как теперь опять по ссылке перейти если "Согласен" нажал?

Comment: @user258184 Функция `add` ничего не возвращает.

Comment: @Igor да задача add только показать блок и запретить переход по ссылке сразу, а как сделать что бы при нажатии Согласен add вернул true, а при Отмена вернул false ?

Comment: @user258184 никак. Когда нажимается "Согласен"/"Отмена", `add` давно уже отработала.

Comment: @user258184 Назначайте обработчики `click` кнопкам `.line`, и в них (в "Согласен") переходите по ссылке.

Comment: Да вообще-то можно же сделать async/await и промис, скажем await-нуть пока пользователь не ответил, а потом когда ответил смотреть чего он ответил, и функция не отработает пока не получит ответ.